# Which user execute a GPO which is granted to unpriviledged user?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, user, authorization

When a unprivileged user (or a machine account) of a AD DS domain is granted to execute a GPO.  Which user actually execute it for him?

Is it possible to choose the user which execute the GPO, Apply the rights, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a unprivilegded user (or a machine account) of a AD DS domain is granted to execute a GPO. Which user actually execute it for him?

Things in Computer-level GPOs are executed by the [`SYSTEM` user](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/120929).  Things in User-level GPOs are executed by which ever user is logging in.

> Is it possoble to choose the user which execute the GPO, Apply the rights, etc?

Yes, either by linking the GPO to an OU that contains the specific user(s) you want to have the GPO apply to, or by using Group Policies' security filtering.

[From Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc781988(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Security filtering is a way of refining which users and computers will receive and apply the settings in a Group Policy object (GPO). Using security filtering, you can specify that only certain security principals within a container where the GPO is linked apply the GPO.

[image: GP Mgmt. Security Filtering]

You cannot apply GPOs to one user, but have them executed as a different user.

Comment: So, the user which apply the Policy depends upon the `GPO` (*Computer GPO* or *User GPO*) which is linked and not of the `user`, `group or `computer` towards which it is related?